# Call to 'getSession' failed The session identified by e4a83445-2606-4710-baac-3786d87761aa is not known

Tags: android, automation, appium, appium-inspector

i am unable to [screen keep on loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnrAo.png)inspect the element ,appium inspector keep on loading

i try to inspect the element but i am unable to do that appium inspector keep on loading
{
"appium:platformName": "Android",
"appium:platformVersion": "13",
"appium:automationName": "UIAutomator2",
"appium:deviceName": "emulator-5554",
"appium:appPackage": "com.zoetis.moose",
"appium:appActivity": "com.zoetis.moose.ui.preLogin.splash.SplashActivity",
"appium:noReset": "false",
"appium:clearSystemFiles": "true",
"appium:clearAppData": "true"
}